# How rounding on DATEDIFF in Millisecond works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp, datediff

I am using SQL Server 2022

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB5029503) - 16.0.4080.1 (X64) 
    Sep  1 2023 09:38:16 
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) <X64>
```

I am trying to get better understanding of how `datediff` in millisecond works.

I tried the queries below, the 1st query turns out that it is rounding down. But then the 2nd query is rounding up.

1st Query:

```
select
    DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.460000000' AS DATETIME2), CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.506866700' AS DATETIME2)) callTimeInNano,
    DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND , CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.460000000' AS DATETIME2), CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.506866700' AS DATETIME2)) callTimeInMillis
```

Result:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|callTimeInNano|callTimeInMillis|
+--------------+----------------+
|46866700      |46              |
+--------------+----------------+
```

2nd Query:

```
select
    DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND , CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.826666700' AS DATETIME2), CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.903333300' AS DATETIME2)) callTimeInNano,
    DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND , CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.826666700' AS DATETIME2), CAST('2023-12-20 23:00:12.903333300' AS DATETIME2)) callTimeInMillis
```

Result:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|callTimeInNano|callTimeInMillis|
+--------------+----------------+
|76666600      |77              |
+--------------+----------------+
```

It is really weird when `46866700 -> 46`, but `76666600 -> 77`. Could anyone explain how it works?

Thanks!

Comment: The rounding is a bit unexpected - at times. Rounding to milliseconds will **only** look at the first three digits after the decimal point - in your first case `506 - 460` results in 46, and in your second case `903 - 826` results in 77. That's correct - but sometimes unexpected.... Rounding in T-SQL **always** only looks at that particular part of a date&time that you specify -  comparing `2023-01-01`  to  `2022-12-31` by month or year will result in a value of `1` in both cases - even though the difference is really just a single day .....

Comment: `DATEDIFF` returns the number of datepart boundaries crossed of the specified datepart. It doesn't calculate the difference and then round it. So `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2023-12-31 23:59:59', '2024-01-01 00:00:00')` returns `1` as a year boundary was crossed in that one second interval

Comment: @marc_s `DATEDIFF` doesn't round, it looks at how many boundaries crossed. And 3 digits is not correct: for `datetime` values you can't get more precise than 0.003 seconds, but `datetime2` is much more precise, other types differ also..

Comment: @Charlieface: sorry - yes, it's not "rounding" - it should be "determining difference". But when you ask for **milliseconds** - you're asking for **3 digits** only after the decimal point - no? And that's what's being taken into account when determining the `DATEDIFF` based on / for milliseconds. Yes, of course `DATETIME2(7)` will have up to 7 digits after the decimal point - but when asking for `DATEDIFF` based on milliseconds - **only** the first three will be considered - no matter how many you have

Comment: A surprising side effect of the boundary counting occurs with the old `DATETIME` data type with a 1/300 second accuracy. The actual fractional millisecond values are used instead of the rounded millisecond values shown in most displays. `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.000', '0.003') = 3`, `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.003', '0.007') = 3`, and `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.007', '0.010') = 4`. Makes sense if you think of the values as `0.0000000`, `0.0033333`, `0.0066666`, and `0.0100000`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z2NN16n6).